# News App integrated with content management system

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push, alfresco

I want to create a mobile news app which will have content intergraded in backend as web content management.

Basic Features of mobile app will include

- Integrate the Mobile App to get Web Content published via web content management
- Push Notification Firebase Cloud Messaging
- Media and Content Management

Currently I have IONIC in my mind to go with mobile app development
Looking for ALFRESCO to handle Web content and Media Management, Not Sure about the alfresco to support mobile notification , Publish Web content on mobile.

Yours help is really appreciated

Thank You

Comment: What's your question? Do you have any code? Take your own time and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi there, Basically I am looking for web content generated from external application using tinymice editor and save in a alfresco, publish on mobile App as a push message. No Idea on the implementation part how i can achieve it using alfresco.

Answer (score 1):

Take look at source code of [Alfresco Android Application](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-android-app)